# Error after moving pimcore to remote server

Tags: pimcore

I have moved a pimcore 1.4 site to a new server, all files and database and although the admin works fine, the following error is thrown trying to access any public facing pages.

```
Argument 1 passed to Pimcore\Model\Object\Localizedfield::setClass()
 must be an instance of Pimcore\Model\Object\ClassDefinition, 
null given, called in     
/xxxxxx/models/Object/Listing/Concrete/Dao.php on line 122
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all files were moved correctly to new server? Especially check website/var/classes directory and content of the website/var/config/system.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I did check these, but the issue was an incomplete database import.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I discovered that not all of the database tables had imported.

I also found other users deep in the pimcore forums with the same issue, so this is the first place to check.